# Configuring the looks of memoir's \paragraph

Tags: sectioning, memoir, sections-paragraphs

I need a lower heading level than subsubsection and hence I am turning towards `\paragraph`. I am happy with not having it numbered but I do want it to stand on a line of it's own and be italic. I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\setparaheadstyle{\itshape}
\let\origparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand*{\paragraph}{%
\origparagraph{#1} \\ 
}

\paragraph{Lorem ipsum}
\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

which sadly gives me:

```
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \paragraph.
<to be read again> 
                   1
l.9 }
```

So clearly I can't renew the `\paragraph` command quite in that way. How should I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\setparaheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape}
\setafterparaskip{1ex}
```

Choose the value that suits you; if you want no vertical space use `1sp` instead of `0pt` as a positive value (even the smallest one) forces a line break.

You probably already know that to number paragraphs you have to say

```
\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}
```

which corresponds to the traditional LaTeX

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

If you don't want an indented paragraph just after the title, say also

```
\setbeforeparaskip{-\beforeparaskip}
```

which suppresses the indentation, keeping the same vertical spacing before the title.

Comment: or the `memoir` way: `\setsecnumdepth{paragraph}`

Comment: And if I don't want to have an indentation directly after the headline?

Answer (score 2):

For what is worth, you must indicate that you're expecting a value, so you have to write `\renewcommand*\paragraph[1]{`re-definition`}` this `[1]` means that you're expecting a value, which you call with `#1`.

See [the wikibook on LaTeX](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX#New_commands) for more details.